# Как правильно верстать mail?

Tags: html, css, email

Нашел информацию, что нужно просто делать табличную верстку и стили прописывать в самих тегах. Но сама верстка почему то не отображается когда я отправляю mail.А отражаются сами теги в виде теста . Может нужно специальные атрибуты прописать чтоб почтовик понимал что перед ним верстка мейла и правильно её отображал...

Вот пример верстки как я делаю :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <table width="710" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-    collapse:collapse; border:#cccccc 1px solid;">
<tr><td border="0" style="border:none;">шапка</td></tr>
<tr><td border="0" style="border:none;">тело письма</td></tr>
<tr><td border="0" style="border:none; border-top:#1667b2 5px   solid;">футер</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом письме необходимо указать заголовок: `Content-Type: text/html;`. В данном же случае, скорее всего, сейчас стоит `Content-Type: text/plain;`, и поэтому html-вёрстка и отображается в виде исходников.

Answer (score 2):

Многое от почтового клиента зависит, можно использовать условия для разных клиентов, например:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0"><tr><td>
<![endif]-->
```

Да и вообще нюансов хватает. [Тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/) почитать можно.